# dc-dc buck regulator dropout

Tags: buck

I am not clear how to read the datasheet about dropout of this buck regulator:
http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/PAM2320.pdf

pag.9

"As the input voltage approaches the output voltage, the converter turns the P-Channel transistor continuously on. In this mode the output voltage
is equal to the input voltage minus the voltage drop across the P-Channel transistor:
VOUT = VIN − ILOAD (RDSON + RL)
where RDS(ON) = P-Channel switch ON resistance, ILOAD = Output Current, RL = Inductor DC Resistance"

I plan to use this buck for converting from 5V to 4.2 at about 500mA and peaks of 1.6A (so I choose a 3A buck for safety margin).

Will be OK?

Comment: Depends on the RdsOn. What is it according to the datasheet?

Comment: 85mR high side (P-CH), 60mR low side (N-CH), inductor 70mR
Appears to be 0.256V so 5V will be more than enough. Not sure is right.

Comment: Vin-Vout= Iload (85 mΩ + RL)  Choose low RL on inductor similar to RdsOn (Pch) for better efficiency

Comment: Then no problem! Your resistance will increase with temperature but you will still have margin.

Comment: @RoyC That's three orders of magnitude wrong.

Comment: No just 2 correcting.

Comment: So drop is 1.6(85 m + 70 m)V about 250mV